# How to edit/create the Sitecore item on behalf of the specific user using Sitecore API?

Tags: sitecore-api

We are creating and updating items in the sitecore tree, we are using `SecurityDisabler` to perform the operation. 
The system considers the operation is performed by an anonymous user but we need to log the user.
`Can you suggest which Sitecore API we need to use so that we can pass a user identity?`
our objective is to track changes whether it is from the content author or any program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I know, you cannot do this if you're using `SecurityDisabler`.

If you use `SecurityDisabler` Sitecore doesn't save the information who made the change.

You should do your changes in `UserSwitcher` context:

```
using (new UserSwitcher(username, isAuthenticated))
{
    // your code here
}
```

If you do this, Sitecore will check access rights for that particular user. So you must be sure user has access rights to edit that item.

Answer (score 5):

We have two options to edit/create a sitecore items using sitecore API

1. SecurityDisabler - It is not recommended for your approach/requirement because **SecurityDisabler** will grant user with administrative access. So the contextUser can do any thing.
2. **UserSwitcher** - It allows a segment of code to run under a specific user instead of current context user.

Here are small code sample with snapshot along with output

> Before code reach UserSwitch

[image]

> After code reach UserSwitch

[image]

Referred from this [link](http://www.nehemiahj.com/2012/03/how-to-use-securitydisabler-and_15.html)